# Can I edit my question to include an answer that produces an error?

Tags: support

I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77137961/django-real-time-name-display-issue-account-not-found-despite-existing-acco) seeking to know why it says 'Account Not Found' when the user types the receiver's account number. The reason I'm asking is that the answer is generating another error in my CMD, and the author of that answer didn't respond: `Forbidden (CSRF Token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP  header has incorrect length.): /get_receiver_infor/`.

I'd like to know if I can edit the question with the answer and offer a bounty, or should I create a new question aimed at resolving this
`Forbidden (CSRF Token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP  header has incorrect length.): /get_receiver_infor/.`

Comment: Did you check the very last suggestion the answerer gave you in the comments?

Comment: "@AdamuDeeAzare: well then it is likely it is the CSRF-token, you should collect the token from the cookie (as described in the link) and add it to the request header."

Answer (score 11):

General answer: no, you should not include answer in the question or rewrite the question to make answers invalid. If you found that a particular answer not working in your case feel free to downvote the answer and/or provide a comment (as you did in this case).

There are sometimes cases when answers clearly offer random suggestion ("try this") or pick a route that already somewhat mentioned (as either tried or prohibited) - in these cases you may try to edit in that information in the question, but make sure to not invalidate existing answers to the question *as asked*. It may be better to finalize the existing by voting/commenting/accepting answers and ask new separate question with more narrow scope /clear restrictions.

For your specific case - it looks like the answer indeed answers the question as asked and your are (as a web developer) expected to have good understanding of the "same origin" policy and all related CSRF issues. It is somewhat rude to assume that the author of the question is  incapable of understanding such basics things related to their field or unable to do research on their own. I don't think in this particular case editing any information from the answer to the question would be appropriate, you may want to ask a separate question (but make sure to do your research on the subject first - there are likely *one or two* articles about CSRF).

Please note that answers normally target the level of understanding demonstrated in the question. In this case you as the author has shown a good level of understanding of the field via good attempt to quite a complex task - so don't expect handholding in the answer.